# 'og:url' meta property displaying wrong path, messing up posting on external sites

Tags: panels, path-aliases, social-network, subsites

I'm trying to post a link to a landing page on my Drupal site, like `http://me.mysite.com/aboutme`. When I post it to Facebook, the link that pops up is to `http://me.mysite.com/node/xyz`. `node/xyz` is an actual node on my site, and content from it appears in a panel that's on `http://me.mysite.com/node/xyz` but it's only like 1/16 of the content of the page, and I have a lot of other panels on that page too. Why is it picking this one? How do I get it to link to the actual page I'm giving the URL for?

Here's a screenshot of my meta tags config:

[image: Screenshot of my meta attributes config in Drupal]

Comment: What's in your `og:url` meta tag?

Comment: It's `http://me.mysite.com/node/xyz` ... what could be causing that? How do I change it?

Comment: Is there maybe a token like `[site:alias]` or `[site:path]` you can hand over to `og:url`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your permissions are correct, you can override the settings for anything.

In your case, override **Content**, and expand the **Open Graph** section.  Then, you can pick the proper token.  I use `[current-page:url:absolute]`

Comment: I'm not finding an Open Graph section on the node override page.

Comment: Do you have the Metatag: Open Graph sub module enabled?

Comment: Soemthing is odd.  I just looked at a recent site, and the section is called **Content**.  I edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Ah, enabling the Open Graph module did it. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently there are two modules called Open Graph that are installed on this site. I'm not sure how they differ but it certainly didn't help matters.